# Automating URL Rewrite IIS

Tags: .net, iis-7

I'm trying to automate url redirects via the url rewrite feature on IIS.
I was wondering what options were available for doing this?

I found out that you can add a simple rule, and generate the script that is produced as a result. The script exposes the variables which contain your simple rule params and Microsoft have an API available which can be used to add rules this way programmatically. The scripts are available in C#,js,appcmd.

However I was wondering if there were other ways that people have used?
Perhaps editing the xml rules file directly?

Answer (score 0):

your could install the url rewrite module

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

and add the into web.config

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite to article.aspx">
      <match url="^article/([0-9]+)/([_0-9a-z-]+)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="article.aspx?id={R:1}&amp;title={R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

or add the rule in the iis url rewrite module in the iis manager,

don't forget restart the iis after add the change